# rails 3 partial depending on locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a rails 3 app for 2 locales (:en, :kr).

I have 2 view files:

```
index.en.html.haml
index.kr.html.haml
```

And each file uses partial.

```
_info.en.html.erb
_info.kr.html.erb
```

(Partials are erb instead of haml)

```
= render :partial => "info"
```

This always uses _info.en.html.erb ignoring locale.

Partial can't be auto-selected for locales?

Thanks.

Comment: I found out the problem. There was a space after the file name and that's why rails couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
= render :partial => "info"
```

Comment: Oops. That was type when I asked the question(I edited). I did exactly as you said but it only shows _info.en.html.erb.

Comment: The problem was with the file name. Thanks for your help.